# ANgular JS and its support for IE8

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, compatibility

Just wanted to know if AngularJS v1.2.15 supports IE 8.
This is because I see few issues when testing a single page app created in Angular JS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, AngularJS v1.2.x supports IE8 according to the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

> **Note:** AngularJS 1.3 has dropped support for IE8. Read more about it on
>   [our blog](http://blog.angularjs.org/2013/12/angularjs-13-new-release-approaches.html). AngularJS 1.2 will continue to support IE8, but the core
>   team does not plan to spend time addressing issues specific to IE8 or
>   earlier.